# Angular 4 - reference to 'this' in observable subscription appears to refer to old data

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-components

I have an `EditItems` component that's use for editing `items`. Inside the `ngOnInit()`, I subscribe to an observable that's in my `dataService` (a central Angular service for handling all of my data calls).

When the observable's data changes, my `subscribe` method is invoked:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.myItemsSubscription = this.dataService.myItemsChanged
      .subscribe(
        (items: any[]) => {
          let lastItem = items[items.length - 1];

          if(lastItem.label.trim() === this.itemsForm.controls.label.value.trim()){
            this.id = lastItem.id;

            // *reference to 'this.editMode' below is always 'false'
            if (this.editMode){
              // do something
            }
          }
        }
      )
}
```

It appears that within the `subscribe` routine above, any references to properties within the current component are referring to the state of the component *before* the change that altered the observable.

For example I'm setting the value of `this.editMode` later on in `ngOnInit`, so that it's set to 'true' if a route with an id parameter is detected, however in the `.subscribe` above, it's still false (there's definitely nothing else that could be setting this back to false). I've verified that `this` is definitely referencing my component. If I reference `this.editMode` *outside* of the subscription to `this.dataService.myItemsChanged`, I get the correct value of `true`.

```
      this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
          this.editMode = false;

          if (Number(params['id']))
          {
            this.editMode = true;
          }
          this.initForm();
         }
      );
}
```

So, when I navigate to the route for an item, for an existing 'item', the above subscription is triggered, and `this.editMode` is set to `true` temporarily, but it's `false` when 'this.editMode' is referenced inside the first `subscribe`

### **Update**

Properties of `this` are only referring to 'old' values when I create a new item (new items are also created with the 'EditItems' component), and *then* navigate to a different route, then navigate back to my item (with the 'id' on the route, so that `this.route.params.subscribe` is triggered)

Here are the relevant parts of my `DataService`.  I'm declaring the `myItemsChanged` Subject as my Observable. `myItemsChanged` gets altered by a separate subscription that listens to a SignalR broadcast from the back end when the items are changed (the `itemUpdated` event)

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  myItemsChanged = new Subject<any[]>();

  //Listening for the 'itemUpdated' event broadcast by SignalR from the back end
  let onItemUpdated$ = new BroadcastEventListener<any>('itemUpdated');

  this.connection.listen(onItemUpdated$);
  onItemUpdated$.subscribe((item: any) => {
    let index = this.items.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.myItemsChanged.next(this.items.slice());
    }
  });
```

Why am I seeing `false` for the value of `this.editMode` inside the first subscription?

Comment: could you put a console inside subscribe of route params and see how many times it is getting executed .?

Comment: Thanks Franklin, it's only called once.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't unsubscribing the subscription, so when I was navigating to another route, then back to the route that contains my component, there was some kind of incorrect reference to the component inside my subscription.

This question about 'when to unsubscribe' provides an explanation and answer for what was causing this issue:

[Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

When using Angular routing, navigating to another route calls the `ngOnDestroy()` method, and any subscriptions in that component should be unsubscribed inside that method like this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.myItemsSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

This ensures there are no memory leaks or unexpected results when re-subscribing the next time the component is accessed.